# Open Chat divs side by side at bottom of its container, Facebook style chat

Tags: jquery, css

I am working with a following code, which is for a basic Facebook style chat.

`.otherarea` div is for holding multiple chat divs.
`.friends` div is for showing online users list.

When I click any user inside `.friends`, I need to show one chat box inside `.otherarea` at the bottom right corner of `.otherarea`

But its not working(shown in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz03Lgwc/1/)).

I want to open one chatbox at bottom right of `.otherarea`, if user click on other user, second chatbox should open side by side to previous chatbox as it happens on Facebook chat.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            html,body{
                height:100%;
                margin:0
            }
            .friends
            {
                height:100%;
                width:20%;
                background-color:#ccccff;
                float:right
            }
            .otherarea{
                height:100%;
                width:80%;
                background-color:cadetblue;
                float:left;
                position:relative;

            }
            .chat
            {
                height:200px;
                width:200px;
                background-color: red;
                display:inline-block;
                vertical-align: bottom





            }
            #main
            {
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(".friends").click(function(){
                    $(".otherarea").append("<div class=chat></div>");

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
        <div class="otherarea"></div>
        <div class="friends"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle, please check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz03Lgwc/3/

I have added `display: flex;` to your container and `align-self: flex-end;` to the `chat` class, that allows them to be shown right next to each other at the bottom.

```
        .otherarea{
            height:100%;
            width:80%;
            background-color:cadetblue;
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            display: flex; /* <- this to the container */
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        .chat
        {
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            background-color: red;
            display:inline-block;
            align-self: flex-end; /* <- and this to the elements */
        }
```

Flexbox is widely supported, but of course, you might have issues with IE 10 and below. [See the compatibility list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. IE10 is not a problem as its working on EDGE. Thanks again.